# Route debug in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana-3

I found code to debuging routes.

```
$route = Route::get('default');
echo Kohana_Debug::dump($route->matches('en/start/index'));
```

When i used code in my bootstrap an error is returned:

> ErrorException [ Recoverable Error ]: Argument 1 passed to
>   Kohana_Route::matches() must be an instance of Request, string given,

How to debug route in Kohana 3.3?

Comment: What kind of debug information you're looking for? What do you mean by 'debugging route'? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want get information. Example in my site dont working url: domain.com/en with route:     Route::set('default', '((<lang>/)(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))' i want check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it looks to me that your Route is wrong. Should look more like this:

```
Route::set('default', '(<lang>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))
```

Note where the brackets are around `<lang>`.

To test whether a URL matches a Route you can't pass a string to the `$my_route->match()` method. Although it does say you can in [docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Route#matches), the method only accepts Request objects. This would make your code look more along the lines of:

```
$route = Route::get('default');
$request = Request::factory('en/start/index');

echo Debug::dump($route->matches($request));
```

The above should output either `FALSE` on failure or an `array` of all routed parameters on success.

If you need more powerful tools you might want to look at [bluehawk's devtools module](https://github.com/bluehawk/devtools) though it seems it's development stopped at Kohana 3.1.x and is not likely to work properly in newer versions, but I haven't used it personally.

**EDIT**

I've made and effort and updated the [Devtools module](https://github.com/michal-m/kohana-modules-devtools). Feel free to grab it from [my repository](https://github.com/michal-m/kohana-modules-devtools) and you'll be able to test your Routes.